# How to get the list of all installed softwares and uninstall the ones which user wants(like add/remove programs in Windows) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, windows, software-center, uninstall

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bits OS** on my machine.

Previously I was using Windows on my machine. Now in Windows, in Control Panel there is one option Add/Remove Programs which lists all the installed softwares and provides an option of **Uninstall** for each installed software. If user opts for uninstall of a certain software then just within few mouse clicks the concerned software gets uninstalled from his/her machine.

My query is how should I achieve this on my machine that is running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bits?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 2):

"We're not in Kansas anymore..."

Click on the Unity Search button and type "software".  You will see an orange hand bag with an A in it marked "Ubuntu Software Center".  Click that and in a few moments when it settles down, you will see four big menu icons across the top: All Software, Installed, History, and Progress.

Click on the "Installed" icon. You'll see the categories of your software.

Be aware that you can't always remove the single program you select. Sometimes they are installed in packages with others.  If so, you may find yourself removing parts of the Ubuntu installation.  (Hint: that's not a good thing.)

Answer (score 0):

to get a list of packages installed to your terminal

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

else you can write them to a text file called packages on your desktop by this command in terminal

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

then select what packages you want to remove and enter this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge <package name you want to remove>
```

lets say we want to remove shotwell from ubuntu. then

```
sudo apt-get purge shotwell
```

but you should be careful as there have dependencies